# SQL Server 2016 migration to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration, sql-server-2016

Trying to migrate SQL Server to Azure, MS Data Migration tool indicates need to delete SSIS. Using advice from Stackflow and others, go into programs and features and SSIS is not listed as a component.

Other advice indicates go into setup and remove components/features will be an option. Using the admin login I do not see that option.

Finally, I ran SQL Server features report and SSIS was not on it. It listed DB Engine services, SQL Server replication, Full text search, SSMS, Adv-SSMS and Data Quality Client.

At a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

Comment: More info needed or this might get closed as "not clear what you are asking". Particularly `"MS Data Migration tool indicates need to delete SSIS"` *how* does it suggest this and at what stage? You should provide accurate copies of messages received and when, as that will help us help you with much reduced guesswork. Do note that SSIS is not directly supported in Azure SQL (though Azure databases can obviously be both sources and destinations for data in an on-prem/on-vm instance). Do you actually use SSIS on these instances/databases or have you in the past?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply. The migration tool generates a report. In it's report, the migration tool listed SSIS as a feature that had to be deleted, it also indicated all maintenance plans had to be deleted. SSIS afaik was not installed and did not show in the features when I checked programs and features. This confused me. I had left the maintenance plans on while running the tool since we needed them. On a hunch I deleted the maintenance plans and SSIS was no longer listed in the report as a problem feature. The maintenance plans were backups, either they used SSIS somehow even with it not installed, or the MS's migration tool was wrong. In any case, with the maintenance plans delete I no longer have the problem.

Comment: Did you make a second account to answer your own question?